# How do I decide between a “Power Drain Snake” and a drain cleaning jet kit?

Tags: drains

I have some slow flowing drains that back up when it rains that I need to clear out. As there are no manholes or rodding points, I can only access them via the P-trap connected to an outside hopper.

I have a basic Karcher power washer that I can get a drain cleaning jet for,  or I could get a Drain Snake to attach to my drill.  Which should I use?

(Rods are not an option due to the P-trap.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a blockage (which it sounds like there is since it's backing up) then you probably want to snake it before jetting since jetting alone is not going to remove a big blockage.  How big is the drain? If it's large (like a 4" sewer line) then a power drill snake is probably not going to cut it and you need a drain auger with a larger diameter and some attachment options.  Something like [this](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-100595071/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053): .

[image]